# Issue with JPanel, JFrame, BoxLayout

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, boxlayout

Hello I am having an issue with this.  I am trying to create 2 panels. One with the labels stacked on top of each other in a BoxLayout and the other panel with TextFields also with a BoxLayout stacked up that correspond with the labels. I have tried various setups and keep getting errors.

I am setting Layout on JFrame as FlowLayout()

and using this to set the panels layoutManager

```
 leftPanel = new JPanel(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

This is something I have done before without issue.  what is wrong now?

ERROR:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: BoxLayout can't be shared
at javax.swing.BoxLayout.checkContainer(BoxLayout.java:465)
at javax.swing.BoxLayout.invalidateLayout(BoxLayout.java:249)
at javax.swing.BoxLayout.addLayoutComponent(BoxLayout.java:282)
at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1125)
at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:415)
at DataWriteExample.BuildLeftPanel(DataWriteExample.java:37)
at DataWriteExample.<init>(DataWriteExample.java:24)
at DataWriteExample.main(DataWriteExample.java:58)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: [`public BoxLayout(Container target, int axis)` -> `target - the container that needs to be laid out`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html#BoxLayout-java.awt.Container-int-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try this instead:

```
leftPanel = new JPanel();
leftPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(leftPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

**Update**

Problem with your code is:

```
leftPanel = new JPanel(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
-------------------------------------^
// here `this` is not leftPanel, I believe its the JFrame instance
// hence your getting the exception of cannot share the layout
```

Comment: Why does that work but you cannot add it to the constructor?  Your method has solved my issue but why?  I could have sworn I used it in the constructor before.

Comment: Hey if I try to add as the constructor with leftPanel instead of this I still get the same error. Splitting it up into the next line fixes the issue.  Should I be able to add the layout manager into the JPanel constructor?

Comment: @Code_Help, if you mean this `leftPanel = new JPanel(new BoxLayout(leftPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));` then sorry to say but this won't work

Comment: You need a JPanel containing those two buttons, so buttons will be center aligned, and add the JPanel to the south region of the JFrame

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60589/discussion-between-arvind-and-code-help).